# How to do hill climbing in R from a given starting point?

Tags: r, optimization

I'm looking for a function that will do simple hill climbing on a vector, from a starting point that I provide. More formally: given a vector like `y <- c(1,2,3,1,1)`, I want a function `hill(y, x0)` such that `hill(y, 1) == 3` (climbing from left gets to the top) and `hill(y, 5) == 5` (it moves left and right, but discovering it's on a plateau, just returns the starting value). I have trouble believing this doesn't exist, but haven't been able to find it so far. Anyone got a lead?

Comment: I can't understand what you are looking for. It sounds like `max(y)` will return what you want in your example. Also note that R has a general optimization function [?optim](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/optim.html).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a recursive solution, from https://gist.github.com/3000200. Tests elided for brevity.

```
climb <- function(y, x0) {
  x <- index(y)
  n <- length(y)

  if (n == 0) { return(NA) }

  if (x0 < min(x) | x0 > max(x)) {
    warning(sprintf("x0 of %f lies outside data range [%f, %f]", x0, min(x), max(x)))
  }

  # TODO: beautify this.
  w <- which.min(abs(as.numeric(x - x0)))
  i <- x[w]
  ii <- index(x)[w] # 1-based index
  l <- x[ii-1]
  r <- x[ii+1]
  yl <- if (ii == 1) { -Inf } else { as.numeric(y[l]) }
  yr <- if (ii == n) { -Inf } else { as.numeric(y[r]) }
  yi <- as.numeric(y[i])

  # At a maximum?
  if (yl <= yi && yr <= yi) {
    return(i)
  }

  # Nope; go in the direction of greatest increase, breaking ties to the right.
  if (yl > yr) {
    return(climb(y, l))
  } else {
    return(climb(y, r))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a function that will do that, the task is too simple and specialized. The more general case is that of finding local maxima in a vector or time series:

Given `x`, then [could be written as one-liner]

```
lmax <- function(x) {
    x <- c(x[1], x, x[length(x)])
    d <- diff(sign(diff(x)))
    which(d < 0)
}
```

will return the indices of all (local) maxima in `x`. Starting with some index `i` it is now easy to find the highest maximum in its vicinity. Example:

```
x <- c(10,10, 9, 4,10,10,10, 1, 2, 5, 4, 4)
lmax(x)                                     # 2  5  7 10
```

If you start with `i = 4` you will have to look -- applying `findInterval`, for instance -- which one is higher, `x[2]` or `x[5]`. If you don't want to wade through flat valleys (or plateaus), e.g. `i=6`, some `if` statements will march in. Therefore a pedestrian's approach seems more appropriate:

```
hill <- function(x, i) {
    stopifnot(is.numeric(x), 1 <= i, i <= length(x))
    i1 <- i2 <- i
    while (i1 < length(x))
        if (x[i1 + 1] > x[i1]) i1 <- i1 + 1 else break
    while (i2 > 1)
        if (x[i2 - 1] > x[i2]) i2 <- i2 - 1 else break
    # return
    if (x[i1] >= x[i2]) i1 else i2
}
```

Of course, I would like to see a more vectorized solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suspected you are looking for either for `cumsum` or `cummax` but are having trouble with your math:

```
?cummax  # on same help page as cumsum

> y <- c(1,2,3,1,1)
> cummax(y)
[1] 1 2 3 3 3
> cumsum(y)
[1] 1 3 6 7 8
```

But then I searched on 'hill climbing' on RSeek.org and see that you want something else. There are such functions in packages: `hill.climbing.search` in 'FSelector', for instance.